# IMAP Connection Error: Address not supported by protocol

Tags: python, imap

I am using IMAP to fetch the emails. It works fine in my jupyter notebook.

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap-mail.outlook.com")
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)
imap.select(

('OK', [b'10760'])
```

But when I use this same code in my remote computer, I cannot connect to IMAP.It shows the following error.

```
 OSError: [Error 97] Address not supported by protocol
```

Can anyone figure out what is the error here?

Comment: Looks like an IPv6 only host and an IPv4 only device (or the other way around).

Comment: Are there any method to overcome this issue?

Comment: You will probably want to troubleshoot the name resolution facilities of your operating system (or if it's Windows, replace it if you can).

Comment: It's Office365, which supports both v4 and v6. My first guess is that one of the hosts has IPv6 half-enabled, ie. the DNS resolution returns both v4 and v6 addresses and some crapware uses just the first address returned, and doesn't have IPv6. Guessing: `telnet -4 imap-mail.outlook.com 143` works, `telnet -6 imap-mail.outlook.com 143` does not. If so, the solution is to finish enabling IPv6. Another way is to fix the crapware.